# Merge Accounts based on Account Number

Tags: urlhacking, duplicate-management

I'm trying to help my users find Duplicates Accounts in Salesforce..
I've Created a nice URL Hack Button that direct the user to the merge Accounts page from the account page it self so I can add to the URL the Account.Name and the page will search for me the duplicates Accounts immediately and enable to select for merging...

```
/merge/accmergewizard.jsp?retURL=%2F001%2Fo&srch={!Account.Name}";
```

It helps But, Is there anyway to search duplicates accounts on the standard merge accounts page based on a different field other then Account Name??. such as Account Number?

Comment: There is an idea that appears to be under consideration, vote it up: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpleAAC

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use the standard UI for merging by name. You could, however, build a Visualforce page that would support such functionality, if you wanted to.

Comment: how do you recommend doing so?

Comment: I don't have time to write that much code, but basically, provide a Visualforce page that accepts a search parameter for account number, returns matching accounts, lets you select 2-3 accounts (master plus two slaves), and then call Database.merge to merge the records. I'd recon this would be about 100 lines of code if you don't get too fancy.

Comment: Thanks..I actually just found online a great URL hack to jump straight to merging page with as many account Id's you would like (Even more than 3).. So I guess an easiest workaround I see so far would be to do it with Visualforce with extension that query the duplicate accounts Id's and assign them as the variable in the following URL : 
<br>
    /merge/accmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=001200000012345&cid=001200000012346&cid=001200000012347&cid=001200000012348

credit goes to -[link]  http://fosnez.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/salesforce-merge-accounts-url-hacking.html

Comment: That would be a viable alternative, although if you're already writing VF, it probably isn't saving much to just finish it in code. However, I don't see anything inherently wrong with using it, as long as they don't decide to break it.

Comment: I guess the benefit using the URL Hack is that I don't need to develop the merge UI page as well. than I can give the users to choose which of the accounts will be the master.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, as standard objects/features typically rely on Name field.

you can, however, leverage the newest "Duplicate Management" feature in salesforce, and set up a matching rule to detect/prevent duplicate accounts with the same number from being entered

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but thought I'd share this as it might be useful to someone looking at this.

**Merging Contacts**
This is nearly exactly the same as the accounts but instead of accmergewizard.jsp you are using conmergewizard.jsp and then the ID's of the contacts rather than the accounts.

for example:

```
https://eu1.salesforce.com/merge/conmergewizard.jsp?goNext=+Next+&cid=003************&cid=003************
```